# How do I expand integer_sequence?

Tags: c++, templates, sequence, expansion, variable-templates

I have a function which looks like this:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t... I>
std::ostream& vector_insert(std::ostream& lhs, const char* delim, const T& rhs, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
    std::ostream_iterator<float> it(lhs, delim);

    ((*it++ = at(rhs, I)), ...);
    return lhs;
}
```

This is my final attempt and I'm still failing on my expansion of the [`integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) I'm hoping someone can tell me how to write a line that will effectively expand to:

```
*it++ = at(rhs, 0U), *it++ = at(rhs, 1U), *it++ = at(rhs, 2U)
```

Other things I've tried are:

1. `*it++ = at(rhs, I...)`
2. `*it++ = at(rhs, I)...`
3. `(*it++ = at(rhs, I))...`

All of them are giving me the error:

> error C3520: `I`: parameter pack must be expanded in this context

How do I expand this thing?

**EDIT:**

[@AndyG has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56603262/how-do-i-expand-integer-sequence#comment99782756_56603262) that this seems to be a [visual-studio-2017](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2017) bug.

Comment: What does `*it++ = ` even mean? Post-increment an assignment *and* a de-reference? Multiple post-increment operators on a single line is really not good.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but providing a [mcve] w/ an online compiler might help us off to a better start.

Comment: @tadman `*it++` just evaluates to `it` in this case cause `*` and `++` are no-ops on an `ostream_iterator`.

Comment: Why are you assigning to that? None of this code makes any sense. What are you trying to achieve? Can you show how this code is used, and what the output should be?

Comment: Your code [works fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06d4ae8b717e5681) for me.

Comment: @AndyG I'll try to get a better MCVE in a few minutes, the code necessary for reproducing the error was pretty substantial in my first attempt.

Comment: @tadman That's what an `ostream_iterator` is for. Pushing things to an `ostream` (like `std::cout`) as-if it was an range.

Comment: Looks like a MSVC compiler's bug. Can't reproduce with gcc 8.3.

Comment: This looks like a VS thing. I've had problems in the past getting it to expand parameter packs for code that otherwise seems valid. Edit : Let me see if I can find the workaround I used.

Comment: @MilesBudnek I'm using Visual Studio 2017... maybe that's my problem :/

Comment: Which version of VS exactly?

Comment: @tadman Typo on my part with the 3. I've edited.

Comment: @JonathanMee: make sure you tell VS to enable C++17, it doesn't by default. Not sure if there will still be a bug, but worth a shot

Comment: @Evg Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6.7

Comment: @JonathanMee From what I see, the workaround is pretty much to reimplement the logic in a recursive form. Then, the only expansion is of `I` as a template argument for the next recursion iteration.

Comment: Similar bug: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/250767/compile-error-while-splitting-template-class-metho.html

Comment: I'm able to reproduce with MSVC 19.00, but it works with MSVC 19.14.  Looks like you just need to update Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a compiler bug with Visual C++. I'm not aware of any easy fix for it other than simplifying the expression in which the parameter pack is expanded. Converting to a recursive approach seems to reliably work around the problem. For example :

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T>
const auto& at(const T& v, size_t i) { return v[i]; }

// End of recursion
template<class T>
void vector_insert_impl(std::ostream_iterator<int> &, const char*, const T&)
{}

// Recursion case
template<class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
void vector_insert_impl(std::ostream_iterator<int> & iter, const char* delim, const T&rhs)
{
    *iter++ = at(rhs, N);

    // Continue the recursion
    vector_insert_impl<T, I...>(iter, delim, rhs);
}

template <typename T, std::size_t... I>
std::ostream& vector_insert(std::ostream& lhs, const char* delim, const T& rhs, std::index_sequence<I...>) 
{
    std::ostream_iterator<int> it(lhs, delim);

    // Call the recursive implementation instead
    vector_insert_impl<T, I...>(it, delim, rhs);

    return lhs;
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    vector_insert(std::cout, " ", v, std::make_index_sequence<v.size()>());
}
```

Here, the parameter pack `I` is only expanded in the context of providing template parameters which VC++ has no trouble with.

Comment: I've gone ahead and accepted it, cause it works perfectly for my toy example. I've tried to build on this answer a bit though here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56653029/2642059 and I'm running into trouble. Perhaps you can provide some insight?